Работа кода в фоновом режиме в flask/django
Допустим, есть сайт, который запросы и даёт ответы. Но мне нужно чтобы он ещё в это время считал время, к примеру, чтобы отправить пользователю каждые 30 мин сообщение. Как это сделать? Использовать asyncion, multiprocessing или threading? И какой вообще есть метод, чтобы отправлять пользователю данные без ожидания его запроса? Допустим, пользователь сделал первый запрос, сайт ответил. Как сайт будет кидать дальше сообщения каждые 30 мин, если пользователь не дал запрос?
Надеюсь на вашу помощь.

про celery слышали? про periodic tasks, например. https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Это уже наверное в сторону websockets что-то и прочих постоянных соединений. Просто как пользователь получит инфу иначе. Либо пользователь должен получать какой-то id при первом запросе, а потом постоянно дёргать сайт сам каждую минуту, скажем, а сервер будет смотреть - ага, для этого id прошло нужное время, на тебе ответ. Для этого никаких потоков вообще не нужно. Но я так понимаю, этот сценарий вам не подходит.

@strawdog Спасибо за ответ, попробую. Но можешь посоветовать какой нибудь по celery?

@CrazyElf Да, я напортачил с вопросом. Ситуация такая: я написал бота,  который долбит телеграм сервер, но из-за этого у меня ошибка скачит, что довфига запросов делаю. Вот решил на вебхук поставить бота используя flask. Ну он и ловит телеграм запросы, но как мне ещё время проверять в этот момент, чтобы пользователю каждые 30 мин сообщение отправлять ?

@CrazyElf Вот я и подумал может multiprocessing ну или что-то такое юзануть. Ну типо пока flask, запросы телеграмма ловит(тобиш сообщения пользователя) , программа в отдельном потоке чекает время и с помощью какого-нибудь request запросы кидает телеграмму(то есть сообщения пользователю) каждые 30 мни

@CrazyElf Но как правильно это сделать, и вообще правильный ли это подход - я не знаю

@strawdog *курс
